# How to display a basic autodesk forge viewer in a vue-cli app?

Tags: vuejs2, autodesk-forge, vue-cli, autodesk-viewer

I was trying to convert the basic viewer example code into a simple vue.js viewer app. When I try to run `npm run serve'(vue-cli).Things are getting rendered correctly and I am getting all the console logs in the console.

But even before the script getting executed the eslint-loader is showing Autodesk is not defined error. But I can see the viewer loaded the document in the background.I will attach a screenshot of it here.

[image]

Can someone correct me with the code for creating a basic viewer as a simple vue.js app?

/public/index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <!-- Autodesk Forge Viewer files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

/src/App.vue

```
 <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  mounted(){
    var viewer;
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
            var token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJidWNrZXQ6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OnJlYWQiLCJkYXRhOnJlYWQiLCJkYXRhOndyaXRlIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Ikp2Vk40bzdBQ0V0ZE81TVpnZ21QMk9WM1RoNFJnRW54IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiMXBQcVhxOFBZVVU0WmtpTURsaGpUSUxCM3I1UEpBWk9kbTY4dTY2R1ZjajhDY3VzYjB3VFVId0E3emZPVk5JRCIsImV4cCI6MTU4ODIzNDEwOX0.zmY_BFmoZgL4TbtSVyTWKlrFdImEKbQTUsfQxBjsPV4';
            var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
            onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
    };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {   
    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');

});
var documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZmFjaWxpb25ld2NsaWVudGJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0';
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
}

  },
  methods:{
    onDocumentLoadSuccess:function(viewerDocument){
      var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
    viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
    viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{

})
    },
    onDocumentLoadFailure:function(){
          console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix your Eslint errors one by one.

1.- Declare autodesk as a global in .eslintrc

```
"globals": {
    "Autodesk": true
}
```

2.- Declare viewer

```
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
```

3.- Remove event listeners if not being used or just `console.log(event)`

Alternatively you can disable `eslint` but I'd never recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

check out these working samples here:

- https://github.com/dukedhx/forge-tools-hub/blob/master/components/Viewer.vue
- https://github.com/alvpickmans/forge-vuer

Answer (score 0):

In the main.js you can add:

```
Vue.prototype.$Autodesk = window.Autodesk;
```

And use it in the vue components like below:

```
this.$Autodesk
```